# Matlab to OpenCV conversion - optimization?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, opencv, code-conversion

I am converting Matlab code to OpenCV "C/cpp" code. And I have some doubts as below.

```
A = [ 2; 10;  7;  1;  3;  6; 10; 10;  2; 10];
ind = [10; 5; 9; 2];
```

B is a submatrix of A ; Elements of matrix B are elements of A at locations specified in `ind`.

```
B = [10 3; 2; 10];
```

In Matlab, I just use

```
B = A(ind);
```

In C using OpenCV,

```
for ( int i = 0; i < ind.rows; i++) {
    B.at<int>(i,0) = A.at<int>(ind.at<int>(i,0), 0);
}
```

Is there a way to do it without using `for` loop?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I can only think of loops able to handle this sort of request.

Comment: Don't you think that `int *B = malloc(4*sizeof(int)); for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) B[i] = A[ind[i]];` would be more quickly on large data arrays. Besides it would not take so much memory.

Comment: @ Eddy_Em :: Thanks for your response...I am using Mat and in my case, the data of A, B and ind are generally of the order 10^5.

Comment: M-script is a much higher-level language than C++.  Besides, MatLab does it internally with a loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an tidy way of copying. I would suggest you define a function
Here is a STL-like implementation of copy at given position

```
#include<vector>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;
/**
 * Copies the elements all elements of B to A at given positions.
 * indexing array ranges [ind_first, ind_lat)
 * e.g 
 *   int A[]= {0, 2, 10,  7,  1,  3,  6, 10, 10,  2, 10};
 *   int B[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1};
 *   int ind[] = {10, 5, 9, 2};
 *   copyat(B, A, &ind[0], &ind[3]);
 *   // results: A:[0,2,10,7,1,-1,6,10,10,-1,-1]
 */
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class IndexIterator>
OutputIterator copyat (InputIterator src_first, 
               OutputIterator dest_first, 
               IndexIterator ind_first, 
               IndexIterator ind_last)
{
    while(ind_first!=ind_last) {
    *(dest_first + *ind_first) = *(src_first);
    ++ind_first;
    }
    return (dest_first+*ind_first);
}


int main()
{
    int A[]= {0, 2, 10,  7,  1,  3,  6, 10, 10,  2, 10};
    int B[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1};
    int ind[] = {10, 5, 9, 2};

    copyat(B, A, &ind[0], &ind[3]);

    printf("A:[");
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)  
    printf("%d,", A[i]);
    printf("%d]\n",A[10]);
}
```